# run Angularjs application fails

Tags: angularjs, npm-install

i try to run an angularjs applic, i understood that max version of node that can run it is 6.17.1
so i downloaded it using nvm, and then i run npm install but when i run npm start it failse and it looks like it downloade dependencis of higher versions that use es6 so thats why it fails.
i tried to downgrade specific libraries by deleting them from node modules and installing again specific lower version but when i tried npm show version it looks like its still use the higher version.
the error message is:

```
  Failed to load external module @babel/register
[08:42:09] Requiring external module babel-register
C:\Users\s313240798\source\Workspaces\Nesher\Nesher\Nesher.Client\node_modules\micromatch\index.js:44
    let isMatch = picomatch(String(patterns[i]), { ...options, onResult }, true);
                                                 ^^^
   SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
        at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
        at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
        at Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
        at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\s313240798\source\Workspaces\Nesher\Nesher\Nesher.Client\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
        at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

i tried to run it also with higher version of node but then the app was on but faild because of th e Incompatibility of versions

Comment: Does the project have a `package-lock.json` or a `yarn.lock` ?

Comment: It had but i deleted it cause i wanted to download all the libraries again but it didnt recreate it

Comment: that's a very bad idea. these lock files are there to ensure you got a set of compatible library versions. if you want to "re-download" the libs, just delete the node_modules folder. just reatore the lock file, and install again (use yarn if it was a yarn lock)

Comment: i saw the project didnt have a package-lock file because it uses node 6, this file is created only in newer version of node

Answer (score 0):

This page has some suggestions which may help fix your issue: [github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1631](http://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1631)

Have you tried this suggestion from the above web page?

```
npm i -S babel-register
```

Comment: the issue with babel registe is only a warning- thats not the problem